# Merging and multiplying 2 uneven Pandas dataframes by year

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have one dataframe 'X' that looks like:

```
ticker |     date    |  close  |
  A    |  2002-01-02 |   20    |
  A    |  2002-01-11 |   10    |
             ...
  A    |  2003-01-11 |   15    |
             ...
  C    |  2002-01-31 |   40    |
  C    |  2002-02-01 |   50    |
             ...
  C    |  2003-02-01 |   56    |
```

And another dataframe 'Y' that looks like:

```
ticker |     date    |  annual weight  |
  A    |  2002-03-31 |       0.2       |
  A    |  2003-02-11 |       0.5       |
             ...
  C    |  2002-01-31 |       0.6       |
  C    |  2003-02-01 |       1.2       |
             ...
```

I want to multiply the 'annual weight' in 'Y' (by year not full dates because they are uneven) to the 'close' in 'X' to get a new column in 'X' that is called 'weight*close' because there is only 1 annual weight per year for every ticker.

Also, X contains all date values of Y but Y only contains a few date values of X.

So then the problem I'm having is trying to merge like this:

```
X = X.merge(Y, on = ['ticker', 'date'])
```

and then doing the multiplication

```
X['weight*close'] = Y[['annual weight'].multiply(X['close'], axis=Index)
```

Won't work because it's trying to merge on 'date' which only finds the dates in both X and Y and then discards the values in X that aren't in Y - but I want them all.

How can I keep all the values in X and do this multiplication by year only?

Comment: Can you post the expected output?

Comment: Simply create *year* variables in both and merge on those.

Comment: I successfully created a year variable for both dataframes to merge on but X has 1700000+ rows and Y has 27000+ rows which I think due to sheer volume is giving me a memory error.

Answer (score 0):

You can resample the dataframes to align the dates. First, convert the data columns to `DateTime`, if they are not already `DateTime`:

```
X.date = pd.to_datetime(X.date)
Y.date = pd.to_datetime(Y.date)
```

Then, group by the ticker and resample. I use the mean for resampling, you may want to use `sum` or any other aggregate function.

```
X_resampled = X.set_index('date').groupby('ticker').resample('1Y').mean()
Y_resampled = Y.set_index('date').groupby('ticker').resample('1Y').mean()
```

Finally, find the product:

```
X_resampled['close'] * Y_resampled['annual weight']
#ticker  date      
#A       2002-12-31     3.0
#        2003-12-31     7.5
#C       2002-12-31    27.0
#        2003-12-31    67.2
```